# Colocar checkbox em apenas dois itens - JSTREE

Tags: jquery, jstree

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para que os ***nós***  `Child 1` e o `Child 2` seja do tipo checkbox em que eu possa marcar e desmarcar?

Obs: mas somente esses dois ***nós***.

Código **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ativar a opção para utilizar `checkbox` no plugin e ocultar com CSS aqueles que não forem descendentes de `.jstree-children`, exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>Folder 1
            <ul>
               <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>
               <li>Child 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Folder 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul:not(.jstree-children) > li.jstree-node > a.jstree-anchor > i.jstree-checkbox
{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
      "checkbox": {
          "keep_selected_style": true
      },
      "plugins": ["checkbox"]
  });
});
```

**[Veja exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/204/)**